# When using ISPF Tables - are keys useful

Tags: zos, ispf

When using an ISPF table are keys helpful?

My table has 3 different row types:

row 1:  type, subtype 1, details about subtype - 1 per type
row 2:  type, subtype 2, name, details about subtype 2 related to subtype 1 - one per type/subtype/name
row 3:  type, subtype 3, name, details about subtype 3 relate to subtype 2 - one per type/subtype/name/details

I can see where keys would prevent duplicate keys but how to do it is the conundrum.

I've tried various things with no joy. I added a row variable of 'key' that includes type and subtype but that is too limiting. I just can't find the right tbcreate setup.